# Error converting types in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cstring, wchar-t, static-cast

I have a program in which I need to use the Format(); function to combine a string literal and a int into a CString variable. I have tried several different ways of doing this, the code for them is here:

```
// declare variables used
CString _CString;
int _int;

// try to use format function with string literal
_CString.Format("text",_int); 

// try to use format function with C-Style cast
_CString.Format((wchar_t)"text",_int);

// try to use format function with static_cast 
_CString.Format(static_cast<wchar_t>("text"),_int);
```

The first one returns error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [33]' to 'const wchar_t *'

For the second, there is no error but the text appears in Chinese characters.

The third one returns error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const char [33]' to 'wchar_t'

Any ideas for converting CStrings to wchar_t *s?
Thanks

Comment: This is SUPER nitpicky, but technically speaking you're not supposed to name variables with names that have an underscore followed by a capital letter.  Those names are reserved by the implementation for whatever use they feel like (including Evil Macros of Arbitrariness).  Just thought I'd mention this as an FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're performing a UNICODE build (which is fine), so the

```
_CString.Format();
```

function i expecting the first parameter to be a wide character string.  You need to use the `L""` syntax to form a wide-character string literal:

```
_CString.Format(L"text",_int);
```

Of course, you'll need a specifier to actually get the `int` variable formatted into the CString:

```
_CString.Format(L"text: %d",_int);
```

If you include the `tchar.h` header, you can use Microsoft's macros to make the string literal wide-character or regular-old-character (otherwise known as ANSI) depending on whether you're building UNICODE or not:

```
_CString.Format(_T("text: %d)",_int);
```

but I'd say that unless you're planning to support legacy stuff that'll require ANSI support, I probably wouldn't bother with the `tchar.h` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not entirely clear what string type you'd like to target but here's what I'd be doing:

```
_CString.Format(_T("%d"), _int);
```

Attempting to type cast a multi-byte string to a Unicode string may compile, but it's asking for trouble because it's still a multi-byte string. You'll need to convert the entire string and not just typecast it if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the mbstowcs function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx